# How to get all the web application of SharePoint.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, client-object-model, web-application

How do I get url of all the web application created in  SharePoint 2010 with client object model using C#.

Answer (score 4):

You can`t. The Client Object Model (CSOM) does not provide access above the Site Collection level.

As far as I know, the only way to do what you want is to create a custom web service that gets the Web Application information using the Server Object Model and have the remote application use it instead of the CSOM.

Answer (score -4):

You can use below method to fetch all web applications:

```
    var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>(string.Empty);
            foreach (SPWebApplication webApplication in service.WebApplications)
            {
                // using 'webApplication.Sites' you can get the result now.
            }
```

you can also refer below url:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628349/get-the-all-infromation-of-sharepoint-server-using-client-object-model

Comment: This code uses the Server Object Model, not the Client Object Model