# Is there a PnP PowerShell equivalent of Get-SPWebApplication for On-Premises ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pnp

Is there a PnP PowerShell equivalent of this CSOM command :-

`$webapp=Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplicationUrl` ?

Which gets the details of the Web Application at $WebApplicationUrl (On-Premises Only)

Comment: Perhaps if you could tell us why do you want that object or what would you like to do with it, maybe we can help you there.

Comment: I want be able to list the web application with the url $WebApplicationUrl so I can find all of the site collections within that web application and the owner of the web application.  Once I have the site collections I can get the features, the workflows and the owners of each site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not look like there are specific Web Application cmdlets.  At least nothing is shown on the [PnP-PowerShell list of cmdlets](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md).

Comment: I had a feeling somebody was going to say that.  I could not find it either.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that there is no equivalent to `Get-SPWebApplication` in CSOM itself because CSOM provides access upto site collection level only.

So, PnP being a wrapper around CSOM wont be able to access the web application object.

[web application in CSOM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a3b51c0-5218-448a-97cd-8e376147eb42/webapplication-object-in-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

[Get web application in CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75157/how-to-get-all-the-web-application-of-sharepoint)